# Varying acceleration while riding

Tags: motorcycle, acceleration, ktm, duke

My motorcycle, a KTM Duke 200, while riding is producing varying acceleration. This is during a single ride. For about a few minutes, the acceleration is alright, then after a few minutes, the acceleration seems to drop. Once I turn off the bike at traffic, and I start again, the acceleration seems normal. After a few minutes, the problem occurs again.

1. The fuel is not a problem, as I'm refilling high grade fuel, which I've been using from a long time.
2. I've checked out the air filter and I clean it thoroughly. In fact, even changed it to just check if that was the issue.

So what might be a problem? Am I looking at anything major?

Comment: Does the turn-off-turn-on fix work when the engine is hot?

Comment: What year is your Duke?

Comment: @Zaid - Yeah. It works. But for like two minutes or so.

Comment: @DucatiKiller - It's a 2013 one. She's clocked 30000 km.

Comment: Carburetor or fuel injection version?

Comment: @DucatiKiller it's FI

Comment: Do you have any flashing CEL lights or have you connected an odbII reader to the bike to pull any codes?   Here's a link to a converter for odbII.    http://lonelec.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&path=24_61&product_id=58

Comment: @DucatiKiller - No CEL Lights, but I had observed a couple of weeks back, that the neutral light would be on even while riding. It happened throughout the day - on my way to work, and while coming back. The next day it was back to normal. This problem has been occurring from the past 3-4 days. I'll try to pull to pull out the codes sometime soon.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a fuel-injected bike, this sounds like an air-fuel mixture problem.

Air-fuel mixture problems arise when the mixture is either too lean or too rich. If bad enough, both can result in poor acceleration:

- In *lean* mixtures, there is too much air and/or too little fuel

  Typical causes for this include an intake leak which is allowing unmetered air, malfunctioning MAF/MAP/lambda sensor and partially-clogged injector.
- In *rich* mixtures, there is too little air and/or too much fuel

  A stuck-open injector, over-pressurized fuel line, under-reading MAF/lambda sensor could cause this.

The temporary "restart" fix makes me suspect a bad lambda sensor; it's quite common for vehicles to run in open-loop mode for a couple of minutes. Assuming this is a narrowband sensor, you could confirm that it is working as it should using the test outlined [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/15388/675).

Comment: This sounds more like fuel starvation to me rather than lean.

Comment: @DucatiKiller isn't that the same thing?

Comment: I've always, right or wrong, differentiated the two between a fuel system delivery issue between the injector and the pump and a lean condition from unmetered air or a mapping issue of some sort.  Perhaps I'm splitting hair but that's just how my mind has segregated issues over time

Comment: A lean condition may be caused by fuel starvation, but isn't the only possible cause. However fuel starvation will always cause a lean condition...

Answer (score 2):

It may be something with the ignition system. Check the spark-plugs. This tends to happen if there is dirt or some type of gunk on a spark plug.

Might be worth checking the throttle position sensor.

The fuel system may require cleaning with some Seafoam or some liquid cleaner that works well with cleaning fuel systems.