# O2 Sensor on 2005 VW Jetta

Tags: vw, o2-sensor

I've purchased a Bosch premium O2 sensor kit with *SmartLink*. It comes with a wiring chart but I have 2 wires that are not on it. My original O2 sensor has a **red** and **yellow** wire along with gray and black. *Which wires are the heater wires and which wires are the signal and ground*?

Comment: I can't remember the colours but the sensor wires are the ones with the gold connectors.

Comment: See this question: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/15387/675

Answer (score 0):

These 2 links should help you out. These 2 video links give step by step instructions on the wiring of O2 sensors as well as how to install them.

Simple, step-by-step instructions to assemble and install a Bosch Premium Oxygen Sensor with SmartLink ..

https://youtu.be/ex1Hki6-NHw

O2 or Oxygen Sensor Heater (the 2 grey connectors are the heater +/-)

https://youtu.be/Z-TOdXKh2q8

Comment: Can you bring the information to SE? as it is, this is a link only answer and is ripe for deletion.

Comment: I think what @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 had in mind was a digest of what information the videos contained.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling - Exactly! Thanks for helping me clarify. No need for people to down vote this, IMHO. I'd just like to see the information posted here, is all. Hopefully The Heretic can accommodate.