# 1996 dodge dakota 4 cylinder 5 speed

Tags: electrical, dodge, o2-sensor, dakota

Bought a new upper o2 sensor but the clip on wiring harness is melted so I want to straightwire them to o2 sensor.

- Harness wires... black, tan, gray, green with orange stripe
- Oxygen sensor... black, gray, white, white

Comment: Can you identify the original position in the melted clip - that will tell you which wire goes with which...

Comment: Sorry.. no. O2 sensor went out so I changed it. And then...

Comment: No melted to bad. Cut both ends around melted clips but can't color coordinate them together

Comment: [Does this Q&A help you](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/52115/4152)?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the pinouts for the truck harness side of the O2 sensors, upstream and downstream. This should give you a sense of wire color and clock location in the plug.

You may need to go to the parts store and take a picture of an undamaged O2 sensor to get things connected properly.

[image]

[image]